# Dual boot with Windows and Linux

Tags: multi-boot

I have Windows XP installed. Recently I installed SUSE Linux, after which SUSE Linux became the main OS to be booted up. However SUSE overwrote the options to boot Windows (Windows XP) during boot up.

If I uninstall SUSE Linux (I've tried), Windows won't be able to be booted up as the Grub master boot will be corrupted.

Is there a software tool which can be booted on CD to modify the master boot record so as to reduce much effort?

Comment: fdisk /mbr (in a dos enviroment, like windows rescue console) will usually make windows boot again. -- itll remove grub, so only windows can be booted, assuming that's what you want.

Comment: Are you using Novell SUSE or openSUSE?

Answer (score 1):

Think [Grub4Dos](http://sites.google.com/site/grubdos/) is the tool what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

actually, if you uninstall SUSE, it will either leave the grub alone, which will leave windows on there and you'll just have an ugly boot menu, or SUSE will fix it on its way out. No linux distro will be written in a way so as to ruin your computer. at least not one like SUSE or Ubuntu. But the easiest tool to put on cd, is simply the windows xp disk. Run through and instead of reformatting, just try and fix the windows install, and it will fix the boot for you by getting rid of grub and reloading windows bootloader. windows is the only os ive ever had remove a grub menu, and it ended up just getting rid of access to my linux partitions.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try as well [Ranish Partition Manager](http://www.ranish.com/part). Worked great for me in the tasks of: Having Windows boots + several linuxes, etc. Restoring a linux boot. Restoring a dos/windows boot, etc.

There are also more updated free softwares for this:

http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager.html
http://www.osloader.com
http://gag.sourceforge.net